# colinearity between complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, hyperbolic-geometry, hypercomplex-numbers

You can find if two rea-valued vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\Re^n$ are colinear by calculating.

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\lvert x\rvert\,\lvert y\rvert} $

For complex vectors ($z \in C^n$), this definition doesn't work.
In this post, they comment on hyperbolic geometry and how to find the angle between two vectors.  [Why do we use cosh to define the angle between two vectors in hyperbolic geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213552/why-do-we-use-cosh-to-define-the-angle-between-two-vectors-in-hyperbolic-geometr)

However, what would this hyperbolic angle mean in terms of colinearity?

Comment: For what it's worth, that expression still detects whether two complex vectors are colinear: $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ are colinear if and only if $\langle x, y \rangle / |x| |y|$ is a complex number of absolute value $1$. This is the equality case in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and essentially the same as for real vectors.